# Append INPUT to TEXTAREA as being typed in JQuery

Tags: jquery, input, textbox

I have an INPUT text box.

As someone types into the INPUT text box, i need it to append/add-to a TEXTAREA value.

---

Lets say user types '12345' into the text box.

The textarea (default value="Comment: ") will automatically add: 'Comment: 12345'. Adding '12345' as they type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `area` is the id of your textarea and `text` the id of your textbox,

```
$(function() {

  var areaText = $('#area').val();  

  $('#text').bind('keyup keypress', function() { 
      $('#area')[0].value = areaText + $(this)[0].value;
  });

});
```

- [Working Example here](http://jsbin.com/otaku) add **/edit** to the URL to play with the example

Answer (score 1):

Russ Cam is missing an edge case -- you can drag and drop text into and within input fields by highlighting and dragging, which his code does not account for.

Below code that covers this case:

```
$(function() {

  var areaText = $('#area').val();  

  $('#text').bind('keyup keypress drop', dropfunction() { 
      $('#area')[0].value = areaText + $(this)[0].value;
  });

});
```

That said, there is still another edge case, which is deleting and manipulating via context menu.  As of right now I can't see a way to detect the selection of context menu interaction...  You could disable it if that is important using the following code

```
$('#text').bind('contextmenu', function() { 
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_input').bind('keypress', function(event) { 
    var char_code = event.which ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(char_code);
    $('#your_textarea').value += char;
});
```

Comment: That gives me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Erm, sorry.  Left off some termination code.  Should be better now.  For backspaces you'd have to get a bit fancier yeah.